# how to give empty for email in json

Tags: json, json-schema-validator

I need to construct json schema for email which will accept either empty or email format.

I used as follows

```
 "emailID": {
                    "type": "string", 
                    "required": false,
                    "format": "(^$)|email"
                  }
```

But it is not validating email id is in right format or not.
even if email is simply A or * it is accepting.
But if I remove (^$) in format it is validating perfectly
how to put both conditions

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all: this is a draft v3 schema; it is invalid against the current draft because of your `required`.

Then, your requirements are quite strange: either you say that the object member is not required, or if it is present it can either be an empty string or a valid email? Something is wrong somewhere.

Not that this is not doable; it is:

```
"emailID": {
    "type": "string",
    "oneOf": [
        { "enum": [ "" ] },
        { "format": "email" }
    ]
}
```

But given your "sloppy" set of constraints I am of the opinion that something is wrong somewhere.